# Responsive css solution for 4 column images

Tags: html, css

I really couldn't think of a fitting title to my issue.

So far, I was asked to only add CSS to a site to make it responsive. So far so good, but I'm running into a huge problem and can't think of a proper solution.

Please take a look at `<redacted>` .

You see 4 images with captions below. This is where my problem starts.

What I want to do: **I want all these images display in 1 column each, the caption right next to them.**

What I already tried: I tried to assign `display: block;` or to reset the given formatting, but there are so many stacked divs that I just loose the overview of the code.

Could you please give me some tipps where to start? I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for  http://jsfiddle.net/fc3nb5rL/15/

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" class="back">
       </td>
    <td>Description</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" class="back">
       </td>
    <td>Description</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" class="back">
       </td>
    <td>Description</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/301" class="back">
       </td>
    <td>Description</td>
</tr>
```